# ¿En SQLite esta bien utilizar un NOT NULL en una llave primaria?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Mi pregunta es, si es correcto definir como `NOT NULL` en una llame primaria en una base de datos `SQLite` para `Android`?, ejemplo:

```
ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: No olvides de marcar la respuesta correcta si ha sido solventada, así la pregunta se puede cerrar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En `SQLite` ( y otras bases de datos), si declaras una campo como **`Primary Key`** **es necesario que este configurado como `NOT NULL`**, ya que nunca debe tener valores nulos.

Aunque en `SQLite` si declaras tu campo como `Primary Key`, automáticamente son configuradas como `NOT NULL`.

```
create table Personas (
  P_Id number primary key,
  LastName varchar(255),
  FirstName varchar(255) not null
);
```

Comment: Gracias Elenasys!

Comment: Ahora agrego más información  estoy en un meeting.

Comment: @JorgeLuisPiloTorres Esto aplica a cualquier sistema de base de datos que estes desarrollando. Las llaves son únicas y deben tener valor.

Comment: Por defecto y norma toda llave primaria debe ser not null
mira aqui el manual de sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con más info. Como comenta Daniel si creas un campo definido como llave primaria, en SQLite es configurado por default como NOT NULL.